# Finding a base of an exponent in mod field

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the following equation:

$$base^{exp} = number \pmod n : base,exp \in \mathbb{N}$$ and another known fact is:

$$gcd(base, number) = 1$$

$$n = 2^{2048}$$ base=13489305024865487703110255658234329747698118206959778644688156332043783846078839120693894255527894489531905012244713117142764166452312133019772171674466933769775907460046497284522592167536594047800489828714315435570429416637425443402332599055774982796405757075108551322778712959943658831605397635195107786224617525627358659165255604556424206194207190437525742567525338826878962081515333896433312311548844614323540250054093970082337500580573165008440265840792908334486258260848163001490152587781983042546491301026074736907693887630347258892882871059741621049169714319440564952700454580681894452760215968494428411686329

number=6870295205307030503255600311283969014496436297715066273709495591567561187646528069669895230912327862244474990612611625088862250315706633708998214109152824455738719595737772769297517386968692628228327225922261219083693899105983726637012353264168761696183327692619506267951701511870035935612090359086376808592001973358166067468618577312983514388332736591060901174314042634365304017788649960016991442596975922402288221898367955532116456798868804571091463566329706023967280838744359633963847966790121312196824818606244189274966061324393424041211903396020720341163472399763951106703068172772579049891895580785347369093113

I know the base and the number, how do I go about computing the exponent? 
This is related to cryptography because I'm trying to decode a message.

Comment: it's a positive integer and it ranges from 0 to 2^2048 @kelalaka

Comment: yup, $n=2^{2048}$

Comment: You state that base = 134...329; perhaps you meant that the exponent was = 134...329???

Comment: oh yea I'm sorry I'm looking for the base, this is my mind at 2am sorry

Comment: what's phi? I'm pretty new to this

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html

Comment: how do I calculate the modular inverse of exp without knowing exp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving discrete logs modulo $2^n$ is easy.

You rely on this:

If we have (for odd $e$) $$(n 2^{k+1} + 2^k + 1)^e = b \pmod{2^\lambda}$$

then either:

$$(n 2^{k+1} + 2^k + 1)^e = b \pmod{2^{\lambda+1}}$$

or

$$(n 2^{k+1} + 2^k + 1)^{e + 2^{\lambda-k}} = b \pmod{2^{\lambda+1}}$$

That can be shown because $(n 2^{k+1} + 2^k + 1)^{2^{\lambda-k}} \equiv 1 + 2^\lambda \pmod {2^{\lambda+1}}$ (binomial theorem), and so $(n 2^{k+1} + 2^k + 1)^{e + 2^{\lambda-k}} \equiv (n 2^{k+1} + 2^k + 1)^e \cdot (1 + 2^\lambda) \equiv $ $(n 2^{k+1} + 2^k + 1)^e + 2^\lambda \pmod{ 2^{\lambda+1} }$

So, you can find your exponent by starting at the bottom, $9^1 = 9 \bmod 16$, and then extending it for increasing values of $\lambda$, until you hit $\lambda = 2048$

Comment: Wait, I don't think I got it. How do I increase my exponent every time? and what will k be?

Comment: is k supposed to be a constant?

Comment: $k$ is where the second lsbit is set; in your case, you have $base = 9 \pmod{16}$, and so $k = 3$

Comment: As for how you increase your exponent, you first solve $base^e = number \pmod{2^4}$, then you solve it $\bmod{2^5}$, and then $\bmod{2^6}$.  Yes, that's some 2044 iterations until you get to $\bmod{2^{2048})$, but each iteration is cheap (and fairly easy to program)

Comment: when you're saying lsbit youre talking about  the least significant bit?, if so won't that be a k=4

Comment: $9 = 2^3 + 1$, and so we have $k=3$

Comment: btw the $\lambda$, that changes every iteration right? it's the (power of the 2) - 1 right?

Comment: and k remains constant right?

Comment: Could you please write this in pseudocode or something?